# mpl_to_plotly does not show the expected legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I'm drawing a graph that shows two curves. But the legend of the graph only displays the name of the curves (computed and measured) without showing the lines assigned to each curve.
It is therefore impossible to distinguish the two curves with the legend.

```
import pprint
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly import tools as tls
import thera.python.utils.theraplot as tp
import json
import plotly.graph_objects as go

[...]
        computed = plt.plot(x, y, 'r', label='computed')
        measured = plt.plot(x, y, 'b--', label='measured')

        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel('mm')
        plt.ylabel('y')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.suptitle(t)
        plt.show()

        plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(fig)
        tp.plot(plotly_fig)
```

Comment: Could you edit your code to show how exactly the libraries `plt, `tls` and `tp` are included?

Comment: Here is detailed answer why it probably doesnt work: https://community.plotly.com/t/mpl-to-plotly-limitations/14686